# increased cost of non-labor inputs and the effect on the value of a commodity (according to the Labor Theory of Value)

Tags: value, capital, marxism, labor-cost

According to the Labor Theory of Value, technical innovation in the production process  lowers the value of a commodity -- insofar as technical innovation generally is aimed at producing cheaper commodities.

It does this by reducing the amount of social labor necessary to produce it. As Marx puts it:

> The value of commodities is in inverse ratio to the productiveness of
> labour. And so, too, is the value of labour-power, because it depends
> on the values of commodities. Relative surplus-value is, on the
> contrary, directly proportional to that productiveness. It rises with
> rising and falls with falling productiveness. The value of money being
> assumed to be constant, an average social working day of 12 hours
> always produces the same new value, six shillings, no matter how this
> sum may be apportioned between surplus-value and wages. But if, in
> consequence of increased productiveness, the value of the necessaries
> of life fall, and the value of a day’s labour-power be thereby reduced
> from five shillings to three, the surplus-value increases from one
> shilling to three. Ten hours were necessary for the reproduction of
> the value of the labour-power; now only six are required. Four hours
> have been set free, and can be annexed to the domain of
> surplus-labour. Hence there is immanent in capital an inclination and
> constant tendency, to heighten the productiveness of labour, in order
> to cheapen commodities, and by such cheapening to cheapen the labourer
> himself.

OK. Within the LTV paradigm, what happens when the cost of non-labor inputs gets more expensive? Suppose a factory needs to replace some machine with a newer machine that is less efficient in some fashion, perhaps due to pollution regulations which have the effect of rendering the old technology obsolete.

Second question: Within our paradigm, the non-labor capital inputs represent "dead labor" as well. How does that affect the equation?

Feel free to provide an answer using the assumptions of mainstream economics as well, even though I am mainly interested in what *Marxists* and their kin would say.